# How does the following "assert_disabled()" macro work?

Tags: c, assert, sizeof

I see this macro appearing in many places in a code base to find if a particular field is disabled or not (0 or 1).

```
#define assert_disabled(e)      ((void)sizeof(e))
```

How does `sizeof` help here in finding if a field is 0 or 1?

Can someone explain this with a working example?

Comment: I don't think it is for what you think it is. Since this expression is cast to `void`, it can't be used in a logical expression.

Comment: The only thing it can do is to check if `e` is a valid type.

Comment: No, it can do lots of horribly-wrong things too. For example, `assert_disabled(int[++i])`... :-)

Comment: @R.. Can you give an example of this? What output would we get on what conditions?

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure this macro is just being used when assertions are turned off. The trick of using `((void)sizeof(e))` instead of just `(void)0` or similar is clever: it avoids evaluating `e` (mostly), but still has the compiler check that `e` is a valid expression, so you won't get surprise compile errors when you change the definition to turn assertions on.

Comment: I would actually like to upvote @PrototypeStark 's answer as well to balance it (R.. is getting all the upvotes :)

Comment: =( I just saw the question and he posted it.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of blackmagic I saw in Linux Kernel codes.

Its used to check expression 'e' at compile time.

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote? I don't think this is a technically incorrect answer.

Comment: ...I didn't downvote. I just wanted to point out that it isn't right to call it black magic just because it is hard to understand.

Comment: @H2CO3: I also find your comment mildly offensive, so please consider rewording in the future.